# How to constrain parameters in regression models in Stata?

Tags: regression, modeling, stata

I am looking for a way to impose constraints on some of the parameters in a regression model in Stata. More specifically, it is a FE panel data model estimated with `xtreg`. I have searched the documentation and the web but with no luck so far.

Is there a way to constrain one or two parameters in the model to a specific value or range?

Comment: Please show us what you did and then we can help you.

Comment: Since this is a question about Stata, it belongs on stackoverflow or perhaps on a Stata list. Crossvalidated is only for questions about statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did your search include? Typing

```
. search constrain
```

in Stata [NB spelling] points up the `constraint` command and an FAQ at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/regression-with-interval-constraints/

Comment: Thank you! I found this, but somehow disregarded it because it did not discuss xtreg directly.